# Strange behaviour with STORM_JAR_JVM_OPTS

Tags: apache-storm

When using the STORM_JAR_JVM_OPTS env-property the properties are not passed properly.

I got the 'problem' working with the storm-starter project (https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter).

First insert the following lines at the beginning of the main method in storm.starter.WordCountTopology :

```
String property = System.getProperty("properties.folder");
System.out.println("PROPERTIES.FOLDER: " + property);
```

Then set the STORM_JAR_JVM_OPTS :

```
export STORM_JAR_JVM_OPTS=-Dproperties.folder=/tmp/properties
```

Now build the jar with mvn package and submit the jar to storm:

```
./storm jar storm-starter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar storm.starter.WordCountTopology
```

This will print

```
PROPERTIES.FOLDER: /tmp/properties -Dstorm.jar=/vagrant/storm-starter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

I'd expect only /tmp/properties and it's a bit strange that the -D is showing. When getting the property storm.jar it returns null, something I also didn't expect.

Am I using the STORM_JAR_JVM_OPTS correctly?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please see this commit (in v0.9.2). Does it solve your issue? https://github.com/apache/incubator-storm/commit/9368ac447aeb473f926302137dbcdf914d06cd32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved in version 0.9.2-incubating of Storm (I was using 0.9.0.1)

Thanks for you comment itaifrenkel!